# Azure storage SAS failed to authenticate

Tags: azure-storage

Hi I am trying to create SAS token for my file on Azure. I am getting "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature" error. Following is my code.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestBlobClient()
{
    try
    {
        string storageAccount = "myaccount";
        string password = "mykey";

        var sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccount, password);

        var shareClient = new ShareClient(new Uri("https://aaa.file.core.windows.net/zttsox20201027154501"), sharedKeyCredential);

        ShareDirectoryClient directory = shareClient.GetDirectoryClient("Output/14");
        ShareFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient("637655759841727494_main.wav");

        var shareSasBuilder = new ShareSasBuilder
        {
            ShareName = "aaa",
            Protocol = SasProtocol.None,
            ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(50),
            Resource = "b"
        };

        shareSasBuilder.SetPermissions(ShareFileSasPermissions.Read);
        var url = new Uri(file.Uri + "?" + shareSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(sharedKeyCredential).ToString());

        return Ok(url);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `Resource = "b"`. When you set the resource as `b`, that means you are getting a SAS token for a blob. Considering you're getting a SAS token for a file share, the value of this parameter should be `s`.

Please try something like:

```
        var shareSasBuilder = new ShareSasBuilder
        {
            ShareName = "zttsox20201027154501",
            Protocol = SasProtocol.None,
            ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(50),
            Resource = "s"
        };
```

For more details, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.sharesasbuilder.resource?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Sas_ShareSasBuilder_Resource.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I just noticed that your share name is `zttsox20201027154501` and not `aaa`. I have updated my answer. Can you please try with that?

Comment: Hi @gourav, can you also please help me to set access signature for particular file only. right now even with resource type f its setting access for shared folder.

Comment: You will need to make use of [`FilePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.sharesasbuilder.filepath?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Sas_ShareSasBuilder_FilePath) property. Once you add that to your `ShareSasBuilder`, you should be able to get a SAS token for just a file. HTH.

Comment: Hi @gaurav, I tried to add FilePath = file.Uri.LocalPath but it was giving me authentication error again.

Comment: Please use `file.Path` property instead of `file.Uri.LocalPath`. I think that should work.

Comment: Hi @gaurav, Thank you for the help. You saved me today. Cheers :)